# Redmine API sometimes needs username/password

Tags: c#, redmine

I'm using the Redmine .Net library to interface with the Redmine API.

Using my API key, I can read and even update an issue.  I can also view at all issues.

However if I want to add a filter, as in "project_id=xxx", I'm always getting a "not authorized" message.  Switching to username/password authentication allows it to work.

Why the inconsistency?  Or am I doing something wrong?

Note: I did have to modify the Redmine .Net library to allow the project filter.  It was a small change though and really shouldn't affect authentication.